# how can i stay longer for response from URL in android?

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

i use this method for send a json object in server and request for receive data:

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest1() {
    message = "abcd";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            G.myurl, js, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            Log.d("***1", jsonObject.toString());
            try {
                Log.d("***1", jsonObject.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("***2", "Exc");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("***3", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                message = "internet";
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                message = "server";
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
            }
            Log.i("***4", "Error:" + message);
        }
    });
    G.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

i receive "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!"
and in server i receive two request from app !!
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks if you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase Time Out Duration you need to set retry policy in Volley so before Adding your request to request Queue Set it as:

```
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    30000, // This is your time in milliseconds for this its 30 seconds
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Remember the time is in milli seconds you can also set back-off limits, and number of retry.

To avoid doing the same request twice change the number of retries to what you want which in your case we want Volley Request `NOT` to retry because if it retries your server might have been receiving two requests so the whole solution becomes:

```
jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
30000, //the number of milliseconds to try out I have put 30seconds==30000milliseconds
0,  // maxNumRetries = 0 means no retry then volley wont retry
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

You can check some official training [from this link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) and explore the classes yourself.